# Не могу отловить checkbox через jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Всем привет!!
Вообщем сложилась такая ситуация, есть список сотрудников и есть отделы. В каждом отделе сотрудников от 10 до 30, выбираешь отдел у тебя меняется список сотрудников, работает всю это дело через ajax.
Рядом с каждым сотрудником стоит checkbox.
Настроил первым вариантом, всё работает до одного момента, пока не выберешь другой отдел.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var UserSecurity = $('#UserSecurity').html();
var arr =[];
//Проверка checkbox
$(function(){$('.CheckboxEmployees').click(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    console.log("Нажата")
    var bufer = $(this).val();
    arr.push(bufer);
    console.log(arr)
    }
    else{
        console.log('отжата');
        bufer = $(this).val();
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(bufer),1)
         console.log(arr);
    }
}); });
```

Если убираешь анонимную функцию то вообще ничего не работает, подскажите в чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `change` обрабатывать

```
$(document).on('change', '.CheckboxEmployees', function() {
if($(this).is(':checked')){
  console.log("Нажата")
  var bufer = $(this).val();
  arr.push(bufer);
  console.log(arr);
  }
else{
  console.log('отжата');
  bufer = $(this).val();
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(bufer),1);
  console.log(arr);
  }
});
```